# How to add a decorator for two classes: <and> or <or>?

Tags: java, xml, decorator, eclipse-plugin, boolean-expression

I'm a bit confused about the logic of logic expression in `<enablement>`s of decorators in Eclipse. I want to enable a decorator for two classes. Should I combine them with `<and>` (it should work on both classes) or `<or>` (it should work on either class)?

```xml
  <enablement>
    <or>
      <objectClass name="foo">
      </objectClass>
      <objectClass name="bar">
      </objectClass>
    </or>
  </enablement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator is enabled if the expression is true. So if you want the decorator enabled if the object is of class 'foo' **or** of class 'bar' then your expression is correct.